# Keeping Default Version of Geodatabase protected?

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, versioning, oracle-spatial, workflow

I have a multiuser geodatabase with Oracle Enterprise RDBMS. The Version of the geodatabase is 10.4.1 and Oracle 11g.

We have over 35 data editors with the flat version tree, each user having their own version, editing their own version. We have set the current access of DEFAULT Version to PUBLIC because each user can Reconcile and Post their edits from their Version to the DEFAULT Version. Now, there have been instances where editors have accidentally deleted, edited the DEFAULT Version directly.

Is there a way to keep the DEFAULT Version protected and getting edited directly without changing its the Access from PUBLIC to 
PROTECTED?

Answer (score 2):

The esri solutions to control editing and privacy in enterprise geodatabase are versioning and setting permission. 
[Versioning](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/an-overview-of-versioning.htm) allows multiple editors to alter the same data in an enterprise or workgroup geodatabase without applying locks or duplicating data.

You can create a version for each of users. Then users only just edit in their versions.

See [link](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/creating-versions-and-setting-permissions.htm) for more information

The owner of the version (the person who creates it) can set who can access the version. Access permission options are as follows:

- Private: Only the version owner can view and edit the datasets in that version.
- Protected: Any user can view the datasets in the version, but only the owner can edit them.
- Public: Any user can view and edit the datasets, provided he or she has been granted permission on the datasets.

To restore to a old version (for example two days ago), use [historical version](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/working-with-historical-versions.htm) , otherwise you should backup and restore the database from Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Open Catalog (use a sysadmin user) and right click the connection to the GDB Administration > Administer Geodatabase
[image]

select your Default Version and use the Protected Mode. Only users who have "sysadmin" roles in the DBMS can now edit this data

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes. I am aware of this option. My question specifically mentions that I like to know if there is any other way without changing the access to Protected. The problem with changing from Public to Protected is editor will not able to post and reconcile the data to Default.

Comment: the question has been edited since my initial answer.